# Compiling Cilkplus-GCC on CentOS

Tags: linux, gcc, centos, redhat, cilk

I got an Error while comiling Intel CilkPlus on CentOS 7.

I can post my config.log (was just a bit too big for this post - if it is usefull I will post it)

And here the last lines of the console output:

```
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C++ compiler works... configure: error: in `/home/johannes/b-gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/32/libcilkrts':
configure: error: cannot run C++ compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details.
make[1]: *** [configure-target-libcilkrts] Fehler 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/johannes/b-gcc'
make: *** [all] Fehler 2
```

Can anyone help me? I just don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the C++ compiler was not build (or not build properly). Can you please post the command you used (along with the tags) you used to configure the compiler?

Comment: I thin you mean this:
$HOME/gcc-6bca773/configure --prefix=$HOME/cilkplus-install --enable-languages="c,c++"